# Dropping Multiple Columns Using Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the below dataset. I'm trying to figure out how to drop columns "Unnamed 5" through "Unnamed 9". I've tried the below code but it isn't working.

Data (named mapping_table):

```
Gender|Age|Weight|Height|Unnamed 5| Unnamed 6| Unnamed 7| Unnamed 8| Unnamed 9|
```

Code:

```
mapping_table.drop(mapping_table.index[(mapping_table.columns.get_loc("Unnamed: 11")):(mapping_table.columns.get_loc("Unnamed: 19"))],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Error:

```
KeyError: 'labels [11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18] not contained in axis'
```

Is there an easier way to do this? I feel like I should just be able to drop with something like 
    mapping_table.drop([mapping.table["Unnamed 5":"Unnamed 9"]])

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(None, columns = "Gender|Age|Weight|Height".split('|')+['Unnamed ' + str(x) for x in range(0,15)])
```

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Gender, Age, Weight, Height, Unnamed 0, Unnamed 1, Unnamed 2, Unnamed 3, Unnamed 4, Unnamed 10, Unnamed 11, Unnamed 12, Unnamed 13, Unnamed 14]
Index: []
```

Code:

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed\s[5-9]')], axis = 1)
```

Result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Gender, Age, Weight, Height, Unnamed 0, Unnamed 1, Unnamed 2, Unnamed 3, Unnamed 4, Unnamed 10, Unnamed 11, Unnamed 12, Unnamed 13, Unnamed 14]
Index: []
```